# Ensuring that script exit on user abort

Tags: php, abort

I wrote a script that has no time limit and max_execution_time is 0

1. I should work until the end of it's job or on User abort (canceling from browser).
   How can I be sure when user aborts page load from browser the script is killed by server?
2. Does this kills script immediately or __destructor of classes are called before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is called by ajax, you could add a event handler for when the user leaves the webpage that sends an ajax request that is handled by a script that kills the other script.

This could be implemented by having the script create a file when it starts.  Then, every one and a while it checks to see if that file is still there.  If it is it continues if not it quits.

The trick is finding the filename.  The way I do this is give every page request a unique user ID.  And both the 'worker' script and the 'kill' script are called with the same user ID in the url (GET).

Comment: You can't do this reliably using an XMLHttpRequest when a user leaves the page: Opera doesn't support `on(before)unload` at all and most of the times a browser won't allow you do to such a costly thing as waiting for an Ajax request to end; it just aborts (a) pending connection(s) and exits.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer. but this is a little unreliable. isn't there any more reliable technique?

Comment: I'm afraid not.  I do understand that this technique is **very** unreliable.  The thing is that implementing this. (I have found it to work a decent amount of time. Usually only on changing pages, not for closing the browser) will at least save you some server load.  I do agree that you should not rely on this to end your script.  But, because the browser is not required (and usually does not) send any data relating to closing a webpage, it is the best you can get.

Comment: Actually I just had a stroke of genius.  Just make the webpage make a request to the server that somehow updates the file and check to see if it is recent.  If it isn't just quit.  This can be very network and server intensive though.  This would be good if this is a walk-away and come back kind of page not a view for ten seconds kinda page.  (It will likely give you thirty seconds accuracy max unless you are willing to push it)

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding there is no way with php to stop script execution when a user aborts the page load on their end. I am assuming by "Aborting" you mean clicking stop or closing the browser while the page is still loading.

Comment: Hi , Yes I mean clicking on stop button in browser. It is possible in Apache (and not lightspeed as I know). there is "ignore_user_abort" PHP funtion to disable this functionality but I want it be enabled and be sure that script is killed (and better if call __destructor before).